# fire jQuery click event when custom command is click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Custom Command in my application, and I got two question regarding to that.

1) how to add CSS ID and Class to custom command.

2) my custom command name is Add so i trying to fire jQuery,click event when I click on Add button but nothing is happening. it seems is not calling jQuery click function...

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DatabaseLayer.TableMappings.FeeZone>()
.Name("FeeZoneGrid_02")
.Columns(columns =>
{
  columns.Bound(c => c.FeeZoneID);
  columns.Bound(c => c.FeeZoneDescription);
  columns.Command(
    command =>
      {

          command.Custom("Add").SendDataKeys(true).Click("AddFeeZoneToScheme");

          command.Custom("Remove").SendDataKeys(true).Click("RemoveFeeZoneFromScheme");
      }
     );
   })

 .Selectable(selectable => selectable
     .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Ajax()
     .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllFreeZone", "Qualification"))
     .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.FeeZoneID))
)
)
```

### HTML output

```
 ........
<td role="gridcell">

<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Add" href="#"></a>
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Remove" href="#"></a>

</td>
```

### JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".k-grid-Add").click(function () {

        alert("Add button is called");
    });
});

</script>
```

what I am trying to achieve is when user click add button it replaces with remove button and vice verse... at the movement I am displaying both in grid custom command

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".k-grid-Add").on("click", function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-Remove").show();
    });
    $(".k-grid-Remove").on("click", function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-Add").show();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s86P/)

Comment: i am sure code is right but its not firing at all ".k-grid-Add" click... i have tested jquery with this Grid "table ID" and click fire event .... i am not sure why is not firing click event

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Are you sure jQuery is loaded? If you put an alert in the document ready, does it fire? And are you sure the created buttons do have the classes k-grid-Add and k-grid-Remove?

Comment: yes that is all true and document.ready fires alert plus i have tried grid table id.click and it fires too

Comment: Can you reproduce the behaviour you're experiencing in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: it does work in JSFiddle but why is not working in visual studio!!! i am running on code on localhost at the movement ??? any suggestion!

Comment: Perhaps other JavaScript is included which is interfering with your code? Do you see any errors or messages shown in the console?

Comment: is not error... i am sure is something to do with kendo UI.... i am trying to use clientTemplete tag, basically it allows me to add my own div and <a href ... so i test if that works!!! otherwise i dont know!!!

Answer (score 0):

Extra classes or other attributes should be added through the HtmlAttributes method of the column builder.

Regarding the events that you are trying to attach - you are doing it when the DOM ready event is triggered. However these rows still do not exist - they are being fetched through AJax.

Instead you should execute your logic when the dataBound event of the Grid is triggered.

On a side note I would simply advise you to use delegated event attached to the Grid body element (better performance and way simpler imo). If interested similar approach is used in this [demo](http://jsbin.com/unatic/3/edit) to understand when the checkbox are clicked.